# Play Framework issue calling render() method

Tags: java, playframework

In my **/app/controllers** folder, I have a class called *HTTPResponseErrors.java*. In my code, I call a web service and if I get an HTTPResponse back greater than 400, I call this file with the status code that then is suppose to render a generic page. The code inside ths class file is just the index method, as shown here:

```
public static void index(int statusCode){
    UpdatedDisplayCounts display = getUpdatedDisplayCounts();
    render("/errors/connectivity_error.html", statusCode, display);
}
```

The *UpdatedDisplayCounts* object renders fine. I have added a System.out.println("Testing") statement after that line and it displays fine. However, the render will not bring up the page at all. It actually doesn't do anything at all.

The html file in question is in the **/views/errors** folder.

I have tried removing the prefixed "/", I made sure the file encoding was UTF-8, and anything else I could think of, but this just won't render.

I appreciate the help. Thanks!

**Update**

This is using Play framework 1.2.4

**Update: 26-Mar**

I am going to try and provide more details to see if I can get this resolved, as this is killing me, haha.

I used Firebug to see what is going on with the posting of the call. The response contains the HTML that I need to display. However, it never displays. I have tried the `render` and `renderTemplate`, and it does not work. Any suggestions from this?

Comment: Could you try to move your template to a different folder and test it. I am wondering if Play's does some special routing for templates in the errors directory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you tried

```
renderTemplate(“errors/connectivity_error.html”, statusCode, display);
```

Suppose that `errors` folder is a sub folder of the folder `views`. See chapter `Result Types` on Play! website: http://www.playframework.org/documentation/1.1.1/controllers

**UPDATE 2012-02-13:**

For met both methods (`render()` and `renderTemplate()`) worked as expected.

Just make sure the the `views` folder contains the `errors` folder and the html file exists in the `errors` folder. Perhaps testing a clean HTML as:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Test connectivity</title>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>    
</head>
<body>
    Test connectivity
</body>
</html>
```

Does it return anything if you check the response with FireBug or Chrome developer tools?

Furthermore I would try to run commands clean and clean the project in Eclipse?

Comment: That is actually what I meant by removing the prefixed "/". That did not work

Comment: you should use `renderTemplate` method instead of just `render`